# Only display some of the given data from API

Tags: javascript

I'm displaying some data on my web page from the NY Times API but I only want the first 4 articles to be displayed. How would I get just the first 4 to be displayed and the rest of them to disappear in JavaScript?

I haven't tried any possible solutions yet because I really don't know how I would do this.

Here's some of the data that I'm displaying from the API but there's like 20 top stories from the newspaper and I only want to display 4.
[image]

```
let html = [];
fetch('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/technology.json?api-key=...')
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    data.results.forEach(res => {
      html.push(`<h1>${res.title}</h1>`);
      html.push(`<p>${res.url}</p>`);
      html.push(`<p>${res.abstract}</p>`);
      html.push(`<p>${res.published_date}</p>`);
      html.push(`<image>${res.multimedia[4]}</image>`);
    })
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = html.join("");
  })
```

Comment: No code, no references. Edit your question with more details

Comment: please add the code you are using so there's a chance to help you

Comment: please post the API response

Comment: There is more context needed here. Aren't you adding the articles to the page to begin with? So instead of adding all articles you receive, you could only add 4 instead. Or even better limit your request to only fetch the first 4 articles from the API.

Comment: I'm not sure good idea to leave here your API key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get only some part of the response, such as :

```
data.results.slice(0, 4).forEach(res => {
      html.push(`<h1>${res.title}</h1>`);
      html.push(`<p>${res.url}</p>`);
      html.push(`<p>${res.abstract}</p>`);
      html.push(`<p>${res.published_date}</p>`);
      html.push(`<image>${res.multimedia[4]}</image>`);
    })
```

But if the API gives you the ability to limit the results, use that feature instead. You'll reduce bandwidth usage (and then, response time)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop to iterate only an exact number of times.

```js
const containerEl = document.getElementById("res");
fetch('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/technology.json?api-key=...')
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((data) => {
    for (let i = 0; i != 4; i++) {
      let article = data.results[i];
      containerEl.append(`
          <h1>${article.title}</h1>
          <p>${article.url}</p>
          <p>${article.abstract}</p>
          <p>${article.published_date}</p>
          <image>${article.multimedia[4]}</image>`);
    }
  })
```